# Sending checkbox data through AJAX in vb.net

Tags: ajax, vb.net, checkbox, combobox, shared

I am trying to send some data from a .aspx form to a function in its
.vb file. I can successfully send data of text box or dropdown menus
but when I try to send data of checkbox (whether checked or not)
it shows an error

**"undefined
error
Internal Server Error"**

I have also tried it using `var advprev = $('#<%=advprev.Checked %>').val();` but still it shows same error.

Below is my ajax code and vb.net function as well. **(advprev is my checkbox)**

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

          $('#<%=btnGeneratePay.ClientID %>').click(function () {

              var comboMonth = $('#<%=comboMonth.ClientID %>').val();
              var comboYear = $('#<%=comboYear.ClientID%>').val();

              var txtEmpNoFrom = $('#<%=txtEmpNoFrom.ClientID %>').val();
              var txtEmpNoTo = $('#<%=txtEmpNoTo.ClientID%>').val();

              var advprev = $('#<%=advprev.ClientID %>').val();

              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "GeneratePay.aspx/Update",
                  data: "{'advprev':'" + advprev + "','comboMonth':'" + comboMonth + "','comboYear':'" + comboYear + "','txtEmpNoFrom':'" + txtEmpNoFrom + "','txtEmpNoTo':'" + txtEmpNoTo + "'}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (Response_msg) {
                      if (Response_msg.d.indexOf("ERROR") < 0) {
                          $('#divStatus').html(Response_msg.d)
                          $('#divStatus').css({ "font-weight": "bold", "color": "Green" })


                          $('#divStatus').fadeIn(1)
                          $('#divStatus').fadeOut(5000);
                      }
                      else {
                          $('#divStatus').html(Response_msg.d)
                          $('#divStatus').css({ "font-weight": "bold", "color": "Red" })
                          $('#divStatus').fadeIn(1)
                          $('#divStatus').fadeOut(5000);
                      }
                  },
                  error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                      $('#divStatus').html(errorThrown + '</br>' + status + '</br>' + xhr.statusText)
                      $('#divStatus').fadeIn(1)
                      $('#divStatus').fadeOut(5000);
                  }
              });
              return false;
          });
      });
```

**VB.net function**

```
Public Shared Function Update(ByVal advprv As String, ByVal comboMonth As String, ByVal comboYear As String, ByVal txtEmpNoFrom As String, ByVal txtEmpNoTo As String) As String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have figured it out. I have used the following technique to get checkbox data (whether checked or not)

```
var advprev = $('#<%=advprev.ClientID %>').is(':checked');
```

It returns **true** if checked and **false** if unchecked.